# I can fetch data in localhost but cannot in production

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, heroku, deployment

so I have a Express Typescript codebase:

```js
 public initRoutes() {
    new TemplatesModule(this.app)
    this.app.get("/image", (req, res) => {
      request.get("https://ik.imagekit.io/scenify/kW7LCO9gy_blKfank60BHO3i.png?tr=w-480").pipe(res)
    })
  }
  private initMiddlewares() {
    this.app.use(notFound)
    this.app.use(errorHandler)
  }
```

So basically I have /templates API route I that connects my MongoDB db to the backend.

So the problem is, In my localhost, [I can access my /templates API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05fYr.png). However when I try to access the /templates in production at https://consumer-grammable.herokuapp.com/templates, it didn't work. The status code was 304 (its not an error, its "not changing").

If you notice the codebase, I've tried doing https://consumer-grammable.herokuapp.com/image, and it works, but /templates don't work for some reason when it works in development. Any idea why it doesn't work? I suspect it was MongoDB problems, and it maybe it. However, I've changed the network access setting into Allow from anywhere, and it still doesn't work. Can someone help?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/304) the problem might be with your request headers; adding `Cache-Control` might fix it.

Comment: so i guess its something like "res.set('Cache-control', `no-store`)" @secan right?

Comment: it works now, i put "res.set('Cache-control', no-store)", thank you! @secan